# long equation addition/subtraction calculator that pulls operator and numbers from a text file

Tags: c++

I have this assignment:

> We want to make a simple calculator that can add and subtract integers, and will accept arbitrarily long mathematical formulas composed of symbols + and - and non-negative integer numbers.

*Imagine you have a file formula.txt with the summation formula like:*

```
    100 + 50 - 25 + 0 + 123 - 1
```

So far I've made a program that will read the file, and locate only the first operand and two numbers ( So basically it only does the first condition, I.E '100 + 50 - 25' gives me 150...) I just need help understanding how my program can GO BACK after doing the first round...I'm sure it's something wrong with my switch statements.

Thank you so much!

```
 char op;
    int left_num, right_num, sum;
    sum = 0; 
    while(cin >> left_num >> op >> right_num) { 

    switch(op) {
        case '+':
            sum_new = left_num + right_num;
            sum = sum_new + sum
            break;

        case '-': 
            sum = sum - right_num
            break;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you already learned about loops and/or recursive processing?

Comment: I have learned about loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend a special case for the first value.  All the remaining terms are of the form *operator* *value*:

```
int sum;
std::cin >> sum;  // Read the first value as the sum.
char opr;         // Operator character
int  value;       // New value or term.
while (cin >> opr >> value)
{
  switch (opr)
  {
    case '+': 
      sum += value;
      break;
    case '-':
      sum -= value;
      break;
    default:
      std::cerr << "Invalid operator: " << opr << "\n";
      break;
  }
}
```

The `sum` will always be the "left" side of the operator.  The new value will be the "right" side of the operator.

Comment: Ohh okay I get where I went wrong. So what you're doing is grabbing the first value, making that the start of sum, then taking the next operator, and either adding or subtracting the number on the right. And this will continue throughout the text file?

Comment: Yes, try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something along this line:

```
1. Read the first operand (let's say num)
2. While there are operator and operands to read
    2.1. Your switch updates the first operand (num)
3. num is the result
```